# Error processing package - dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm new to ubuntu. While installing the `node.js` package, it recommended to run `sudo apt-get -f install` but when I run the command I got some errors about dependency problems

[image: dependency problems, leaving unconfigured]

Can someone help me regarding this problem?

Comment: You can copy the output with CTRL-SHIFT-C (don't ask my why it isn't the usual CTRL-C). Paste your output here so we can take a look.

Comment: Reinstall the `update-notifier-common` package.

Comment: @JimDeadlock It's not the "standard" `CTRL`+`C` because that is used to kill the current running job in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to configure the update notifier:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall update-notifier
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure update-notifier
```

then install the ms core fonts/flash and accept the eula:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer flashplugin-installer
```

if you don't get prompted to accept the EULA stuff, do this next:

install flash plugin:

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/install_plugin
```

install the fonts from M$

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: sudo apt install --reinststall update-notifier[sudo] password for mohit: 
**E: Command line option --reinststall is not understood in combination with the other options**

Comment: that was a misspelling.... fixed